# CloudFormation: WAF Association always fails with Internal Failure

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-waf

I am trying to associate Web ACL to API gateway. I am using WAFv2. The snippet of my code is as below-

```
WAFAssociation:
    Type: 'AWS::WAFv2::WebACLAssociation'
    Properties:
      WebACLArn: 
      - Fn::ImportValue: 
            !Sub "${AWS::Region}-${AWS::AccountId}-APIGateway-WebACL"
      ResourceArn: !Sub
        - "arn:${AWS::Partition}:apigateway:{AWS::Region}::/restapis/{api}/stages/{stageName}"
        - api: !Ref RestApi
```

I have referred https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-webaclassociation.html for this and written it. I am trying to deploy this resource in a stack, but this resource deployment always getting failed with error **"Internal Failure"**. I am not able to find the rootcause of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ResourceArn` is incorrect. Its missing `$` in few places. Please have a look at the following form:

```
  ResourceArn: !Sub
    - "arn:${AWS::Partition}:apigateway:${AWS::Region}::/restapis/${api}/stages/${stageName}"
    - api: !Ref RestApi
```

Also, please check [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html#w2ab1c25c28c59c11) from docs:

```
Name: !Sub
  - www.${Domain}
  - { Domain: !Ref RootDomainName }
```

In addition please make sure that all the external components are correct, such as `stageName` and `RestApi`.

Comment: Ohh, I missed those $ signs. Thanks Marcin.

Comment: @SwanandGajendragadkar No problem. Glad it worked out.

Comment: These $ signs were the issue for sure. I added them and made sure of all external components. Still facing Internal Failure error for WebAclAssociation. Is there any way to find actual root cause?

Comment: @SwanandGajendragadkar Try doing this over console first. If this works, try to identify what's done different in the console than in the CFN. Maybe some permissions are needed, other settings?

Comment: Above comment helped for my problem. I tried first with Console. It worked fine. Then I tried with AWS CLI and understood the problem. In API resource Arn, stage-name is case-sensitive. That was the issue. Thanks @marcin

Comment: @SwanandGajendragadkar Glad it worked out. Thanks for letting me know :-)